# convert curl to guzzle for spreedly API

Tags: php, laravel, curl, guzzle, spreedly

I'm trying to convert this curl call to guzzle:

```
curl https://core.spreedly.com/v1/gateways/CAL6uXHtGfDsxV2kW6apTP5JhG/purchase.xml \
-u 'Ll6fAtoVY5hTGlJEmtpo5YTS:RKOCG5D8jhgfdDSg524u5iF22XD4Io5VXmyzdCptrvHFTTSy' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/xml' \
-d '<transaction>
      <payment_method_token>ZgPNHes541EMlBN86glRDKRexzq</payment_method_token>
      <amount>100</amount>
      <currency_code>USD</currency_code>
    </transaction>'
```

I'm know use this so much so any help will be appreciated

This is what I've tried, but I always get this error "Client error response
[status code] 422
[reason phrase] Unprocessable Entity"

```
$xml =  '<transaction>\n';
$xml .=     '<payment_method_token>$payment_method_token</payment_method_token>\n';
$xml .=     '<amount>100</amount>\n';
$xml .=     '<currency_code>USD</currency_code>\n'
$xml .= '<transaction>\n';
$headers = ['Content-Type' => 'application/xml', 'auth' => ['Ll6fAtoVY5hTGlJEmtpo5YTS', 'RKOCG5D8jhgfdDSg524u5iF22XD4Io5VXmyzdCptrvHFTTSy']];
$client = new Client('https://core.spreedly.com/v1/gateways/CAL6uXHtGfDsxV2kW6apTP5JhG/purchase.xml');
$requestCurl = $client->post('', $headers, $xml,[]);
$response = $requestCurl->send()->xml();
dd($response);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Well for one thing `$payment_method_token` isn't going to be evaluated because it is inside single-quotes instead of double. Maybe try spitting out your `$xml` variable before sending it, to make sure it looks good?

Comment: Yes I did that change and $xml looks good...now I have this error "Client error response
[status code] 401
[reason phrase] Unauthorized" I'm sure the credential are right...maybe I'm missing some sintax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should look something like this:

```
$client = new Client('https://core.spreedly.com/v1/gateways/merchant_id');

$xml = '<...>';
$options = [
    'headers'   => [ 'Content-Type' => 'application/xml' ],
    'auth'      => ['username', 'password'],
    'body'      => $xml,
];

$response = $client->post('/purchase.xml', $options);
```

and you might want to take another look at your code and figure out if you've accidentally posted your API credentials publicly.

Comment: What is the right way to do the post without posting the api credentials publicly?

Comment: @AndrésBaquerizoNúñez you misunderstand. You've publicly posted you credentials *on this site* in your original post.

Comment: No, don't worry I changed them before posting this.

Answer (score 0):

If you reference the Guzzle Docs for working with [Clients](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/clients.html) you will see that you can set the base_url, headers and authentication for all requests that are made with the client.

The difference between my example below and Sammitch's above is that I have added the header and authentication as defaults to the client.  This will allow to to make subsequent calls to your api without having to add these as options to each request.

For troubleshooting purposes I simply attach the LogSubscriber so that the http request and response are readily available.

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'base_url' => ['https://core.spreedly.com/{version}/gateways/{merchant_id}/', [
        'version' => 'v1',
        'merchant_id' => $merchant_id
    ]],
    'defaults' => [
        'headers'       => ['Content-Type' => 'application/xml'],
        'auth'          => [$username, $pw],
]]);
/**
* Attach a log subscriber is configured to log the full request and response message using echo() calls.
**/
$client->getEmitter()->attach(new GuzzleHttp\Subscriber\Log\LogSubscriber(null, GuzzleHttp\Subscriber\Log\Formatter::DEBUG));

$response = $client->post('purchase.xml', [
    'body' => $xml
]);
```